# CV error larger then test set prediction error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm using scikit-learn's `RandomForestRegressor` to build a model for one of my data-sets, along with `GridSearchCV` to determine model hyperparameters. I evaluate the predictive capability of the model by splitting the total data-set into train and test sets with an 80/20 split. Model selection using the grid search is performed on the train set and the best model is then used to predict on the test set. I'm consistently seeing that the CV R^2 score for the best grid searched model is lower than the R^2 score when using that model to predict the independent test data. This persists across multiple random train/test splits. This behavior seems pretty odd to me, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, if this behavior is actually normal, or if it's possible that my data is just really quirky.

The pertinent code is below (I'm also using PCA on the input features as part of my modeling pipeline). My input data consists of 3 features (after PCA), my target data consists of 5 features, and the data-set contains 100 samples.

```
# Split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# Feature transformation and model fitting pipeline
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
pipe = Pipeline([('pca', pca), ('rf', clf)])

# Cross validation
cv = KFold(len(Y_train), n_folds=10, random_state=0)

# Grid search
grid_max_depth = [1, 2, 3, None]
grid_max_features = [1, 2, 3, 'auto']
grid_min_samples_split = [1, 2, 3]
grid_min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 3]
param_grid = {'rf__max_depth': grid_max_depth, 'rf__max_features': grid_max_features, 'rf__min_samples_split': grid_min_samples_split, 'rf__min_samples_leaf': grid_min_samples_leaf}
clf_grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='r2', verbose=1, n_jobs=2)

# Fit model
clf_grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Get best cross-validation score from grid search
cv_score = clf_grid.best_score_

# Predict independent test data, score prediction
test_score = clf_grid.best_estimator_.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

Example CV and test set R^2 scores from 5 different random train/test splits are:

```
cv_score    |    test_score
---------------------------
0.4556      |    0.6061
0.5005      |    0.6568
0.4566      |    0.5293
0.4767      |    0.6806
0.5222      |    0.6404
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the KFold cross validation scores compare for k=5 and k=10?

Comment: The CV scores for k=5 seem to be about 1-5% larger than the scores for k=10. The overall trend of test score > CV score is unchanged.

Comment: train/test split are random samples and inner cv splits contiguous? Maybe some sort of drift in your data?

Comment: That's a good thought, but there is no structure to the data (features extracted from CT images of different patients) based simply on how the samples are ordered. I did try generating the different train/test splits using `KFold` instead of `train_test_split` and saw no change in the observed behavior.

Comment: @eickenberg I thought about that but X_train is shuffled by the outer train test split.

Comment: Smaller k should incur lower CV perf as there is less training data. CV score could be lower than test score as the test model has been trained on the whole X_train data while CV models were trained on 90% of X_train each. But the difference seems too big.

Comment: @ogrisel Yeah I think maybe if I was using a smaller number of folds that could be an explanation. Since the grid search effectively fits the hyperparameters to the cross-validation folds I would expect the CV score to almost always be an optimistic estimate of prediction performance. Maybe with random forest this effect is outweighed by using only 90% of the training data?